# Retrieve E-mail address of altRecipient attribute of a user in AD

Tags: c#, webforms

Am currently working on a Webforms Webapplication in C# and need to import the value of email address of the altRecipient attribute in Active Directory. I've been struggling with this for days now and can't seem to get it right.
The 'altRecipient' attribute returns a path//: that leads to the DistinguishedName. So i get something like this CN=edward-audi,OU=AUe,OU=daimler Mail,DC=diamler,DC=net.The returned value is the CN and the email address i need, is within the CN specifically where OU=daimler Mail. Am not sure if am doing the right thing. Maybe my approach is totally wrong.

```
SearchResultCollection result;
 

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DC=mycompany,DC=net")
     {
       SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
       Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=*" + UserName + "*))"
     };
      result = search.FindAll();
    
      foreach (SearchResult sr in result)
       {
          dr = table.NewRow(); 
          DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
         if (de.Properties["altRecipient"].Value != null && de.Properties["altRecipient"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
           {
              string userID = de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
              string Domain = "domain.net";
              PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);
              UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userID);
              if (up != null)
              {
                string userPrincipal = up.ToString();
                de = up.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                string altRecepientCN = de.Properties["altRecipient"].Value.ToString();
                UserPrincipal altRecepientValue = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, altRecepientCN);                      
              }
           }
       }
```